# XML Data at root level is invalid

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code to get a user's profile and return it to a page, the problem I've been having is that I occasionally get XML error data at root level is invalid. Is there a way I could catch this?

```
public static Profile GetProfile(string username)
{
    // We cache the profile for 1 minute so we can speed up access, but still return fairly fresh profiles

    // lock for thread safety
     Profile profile = null;
     lock (s_profileCache)
    {
        if (!s_profileCache.TryGetValue(username, out profile)
            || profile.CreateTime < DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1))
        {
            // missing or stale, fetch it
            profile = RetrieveProfile(username);

            // save it in the cache

            s_profileCache[username] = profile;

            // Store purchases in purchase cache, if not already present (puchases don't change
            // so probably no point overwriting them?)
            foreach (var p in profile.Purchases)
            {
                Purchase purchase = null;
                s_purchaseCache[p.Id] = purchase;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are going to have to show use a bit of your Xml

Comment: If the error is an `Exception`, you can `catch` it if you `try`... but I guess that's not really your question, so please provide a [mcve] of your problem.